# Ambiguous reference to member OCKCarePlanActivity 'assessment

Tags: ios, carekit

Using Xcode 9.4, Swift 3 and CareKit framework 1.2.1  Error Message:

> Ambiguous reference to member OCKCarePlanActivity 'assessment (withIdentifier:groupIdentifier:title:text:tintColor:resultResettable:schedule:userInfo:thresholds:optional:)'

Here is the code.

```
    let pulseActivity = OCKCarePlanActivity
            .assessment(withIdentifier: ActivityIdentifier.pulse.rawValue,
                        groupIdentifier: nil,
                        title: "Pulse",
                        text: "Do you have one?",
                        tintColor: UIColor.darkGreen(),
                        resultResettable: true,
                        schedule: CarePlanData.dailyScheduleRepeating(occurencesPerDay: 1),
                        userInfo: ["ORKTask": AssessmentTaskFactory.makePulseAssessmentTask()]
)
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Newer CareKit framework added Optional parameter.

```
let pulseActivity = OCKCarePlanActivity
        .assessment(withIdentifier: ActivityIdentifier.pulse.rawValue,
                    groupIdentifier: nil,
                    title: "Pulse",
                    text: "Do you have one?",
                    tintColor: UIColor.darkGreen(),
                    resultResettable: true,
                    schedule: CarePlanData.dailyScheduleRepeating(occurencesPerDay: 1),
                    userInfo: ["ORKTask": AssessmentTaskFactory.makePulseAssessmentTask()],
                    optional: true) //--> NEW
```

This change fixed my error. Hope it will help others.